# Заменить символ '/' на "\\"

Tags: c++

Нужно в строке заменить все символы `/` на `\\`. Делал следующим образом:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
    if(s[i] == '/')
    {
        s.replace(i, 1, "\\");
    }
}
```

Но почему-то получается так, что символ `/` заменяется только на `\`, а не на `\\`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Дело в том, что `"\\"` и есть одиночный бекслеш. Попробуйте `"\\\\"`.

---

В C++ в строковых литералах `\` является специальным экранирующим символом: он означает не себя, а просто модифицирует значение следующего за ним символа. Например, `\n` означает не бекслеш и символ `n`, а перевод строки, символ с кодом 0x10.

Поэтому сам по себе бекслеш не означает бекслеш. Для ввода бекслеша нужно использовать `\\`.

Вы можете проверить длину строки `"\\\\"`, она равна 2. (Проверка: http://ideone.com/DhxHe8)

---

Это, кстати, возможно, и есть причина странного поведения редактора по отношению к двойному бекслешу.

Comment: да, сработало. А почему так?

Comment: @RomaMikov: Дописал ответ.

Comment: Это не только в С++, но много где. Почти стандарт de facto.

Answer (score 3):

Напишите так:

```
s.replace(i, 1, "\\\\");
```

Comment: да, сработало. А почему так?

Comment: Потому что символ \ является началом управляющей последовательности - ну, как в `\n`, например. Соответственно, чтобы представить символ \ сам по себе, используется управляющая последовательность \\.

Comment: А если слэшей много и строк для замены тоже много, да еще они и  очень длинные?

Comment: Тогда используйте **необработанные строковые литералы** (см., например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.120%29.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

Или так:

```
s.replace(i, 1, R"(\)");
```